# Discrete simulation of a continuous-time discrete state stochastic process - Convergence of simulation's cdf to the process's cdf?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $X_t$ be a continuous-time stochastic process on the state space {'off', 'on'}.
Let $U$ be the cumulative duration spent 'on' during a time interval $[0,\tau]$ (that is, $U$ is the *uptime* during that interval).

Suppose that we simulate $U$ by sampling on an equispaced grid, as in:

- Choose $\delta t > 0$ such that $m = \tau / \delta t$ is an integer.
- Put $t_k = (k-1) \cdot \delta t$ for $k = 1 \dots m$.
- Put $Y_k = X_{t_k}$ for $k = 1 \dots m$.
- For any realization of $X_t$, put
  $V = (Y_1 + Y_2 + \dots Y_m) \cdot \delta t$.

Let $F(u) = Pr(U \leq u)$ be the cumulative distribution function for $U$ (*intuitively*, the *process's cdf*), and $G(u) = Pr(V \leq u)$ be the cumulative distribution function for $V$ (*intuitively*, the *simulation's cdf*).

**When does $G$ converge (pointwise/uniformly) to $F$ as $\delta t \rightarrow 0$?**

*My attempt at an answer*: A realization of $X_t$ will be *misclassified* if it has sojourns 'on' that are of duration less than $\delta t$. As $\delta t \rightarrow 0$, the probability of obtaining a misclassified realization converges to zero.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After some pondering, I think I have an answer for pointwise convergence.

**Proposition**: For any $ u \in [0,\tau] $ and $ \epsilon > 0 $, there exists $ \delta t' > 0 $ such that if $ \delta t < \delta t' $ then
$
   \lvert G(u) - F(u) \rvert < \epsilon
$.

*Proof*:
For any $x_t : [0,\tau] \rightarrow {0,1}$ put
\begin{align*}
    \lambda(x_t) &= \int_{0}^{\tau} x_t \, dt
\\
    \mu(x_t; \delta t) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \tau/\delta t \rfloor} x_{t_k} \delta t \ \text{where}\ t_k = k \cdot \delta t
\end{align*}
Put
\begin{align*}
    \chi(u; \delta t) &= \{ x_t :
        \lambda(x_t) = u \ \text{but}\ \mu(x_t; \delta t) \neq u \, \,\text{or}\, \,
        \lambda(x_t) \neq u \ \text{but}\ \mu(x_t; \delta t) =u
    \}
\\
    \xi(u; \delta t) &= Pr\bigl( X_t \in \chi(u; \delta t) \bigr)
\end{align*}
For any $ u \in [0,\tau] $, $ 0 \leq \xi(u; \delta t) \leq 1 $ (by definition of probabilities) and
$ \xi(u; \delta t) \rightarrow 0 $ (pointwise) as $ \delta t \rightarrow 0 $.
By the [bounded convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Bounded_convergence_theorem), there exists $ \delta t' $ such that if
$ \delta t < \delta t' $ then
$$
   \int_{[0,\tau]} \xi(u; \delta t) \, du < \epsilon
$$
Hence if $ \delta t < \delta t' $ then
$$
   \lvert G(u) - F(u) \rvert 
   =
   \int_{0}^{u} \xi(u; \delta t) \, du
   < 
   \epsilon
$$