# Probability of short sojourns in an alternating renewal process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, renewal-processes

Let $X_t$ be an alternating renewal process on the state space {'off', 'on'}. We can think of the process as *sojourning* in those states.
Let $[0,\tau]$ be an interval of time and $s < \tau$.

**What is the probability that during $[0,\tau]$, the process has at least one sojourn of duration less than $s$ ?** 
(eg It flicks from 'on' to 'off' and then back to 'on' within duration $s$, at least once during the time interval.)

(I'm attempting to address [an earlier question that I posed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282980/discrete-simulation-of-a-continuous-time-discrete-state-stochastic-process-con), with specialization to alternating renewal processes.)